# properties and methods of strings and numbers JavaScript

Tags: javascript

The objects have properties and methods in Javascript.

[image]

The primitive data types don't have properties and methods.

[image]

But I don't understand from where properties and methods come from of strings and numbers.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

It's because actually is [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) object.

It's internally converted to one of [global objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects) (sorry for my terminology).

Comment: No, `"string"` is not actually a `String` object.